# Xamarin.Forms.Android no longer shows permission popup after reinstall

Tags: xamarin.forms

Developing a Xamarin.Forms.Android app which asks for some permissions, among other location, on start. Recently it stopped asking for permission, as if it had already asked two times, which is the current limit for newer Android, as far as I understand.

```
Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>()
```

Returns denied on first call.

Previously this happened only after the second start, where it was denied, but now, even when I uninstall, clean, rebuild, reinstall the app on the device, it goes directly to denied.

I can still go into apps permission settings manually and turn it on, which works fine, though obviously not very elegant.

Why would this happen on latest Android and latest stable xamarin.forms. Again, I realize that this is expected behavior after two user refusals first, but for a reinstalled application?

Comment: The expected behaviour is like you say. In the apps lifetime if the user denies two times, then the app won't ask again. This is for Android 11+. What version are you trying on? Have you tried the same with other permissions?

Comment: I had done a demo and test it on the simulator Android 11 and Android 12. It also stopped asking for permission, as if it had already asked two times. But when I uninstalled it from the simulator and run the project again, it will ask for permission again too.

Comment: Can you try on a physical device and see if it's the same? When i uninstall my app and deploy it again, permissions reset.

Comment: I am currently only asking for location, and are doing this on a physical device with android 11. I tried it on another phone with android 10 where it does not seem to be an issue. It makes perfect sense that it should only ask twice and then default to denied, but after uninstall, I would expect it to reset, so I have two tries again. That is not the case

Comment: I had test it on the Xiaomi with Android 9 and GooglePixel with Android 10. Both of them will ask for permisson when I uninstall it and run the project again. In addition, the Google Pixel run failed berore I selected to uninstall for all users which will remove all the data about the project.@JoeTaicoon

Answer (score 0):

This is a known "feature" of Android 11+

Apparently you need to first request when-in-use permission and ***only then*** always permission.

```
var whenInUse = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
var always = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>();
```

https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-only-foreground